# Does Scrapy 'know' when it has crawled an entire site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have used Beautiful Soup with great success when crawling single pages of a site, but I have a new project in which I have to check a large list of sites to see if they contain a mention or a link to my site. Therefore, I need to check the entire site of each site.

With BS I just don't know yet how to tell my scraper that it is done with a site, so I'm hitting recursion limits. Is that something Scrapy handles out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy uses a link follower to traverse through a site, until the list of available links is gone.  Once a page is visited, it's removed from the list and Scrapy makes sure that link is not visited again.

Assuming all the websites pages have links on other pages, Scrapy would be able to visit every page of a website.

I've used Scrapy to traverse thousands of websites, mainly small businesses, and have had no problems.  It's able to walk through the whole site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The docs and tutorials I'm seeing are for crawling one domain. Do you know where I should look for how to crawl a list of domains? Maybe I'm just not using the right keywords.

Comment: I'd use this tutorial -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnnDshuflSI -- it will provide a great framework for you to build off of.  Take your time and learn what he's teaching.  He works with Scrapy so its a great tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, no one knows when it crawled entire site. Can you say when you crawled entire Facebook, for example? That is because dynamically generated and cross-linked pages.

To set recursion limit is the only way to plan border after which you will stop your movement. But you can minimise the number of duplicate pages. You can use page link or page text's CRC as identifier and check if it is unique.

You can do something like this in your `parse` method:

```
if some_id not in set_of_all_page_ids:
    set_of_all_page_ids.add(some_id)
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```